# node.js express server keep gain memory in queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, garbage-collection

I'm trying to understand how to achieve better performance with node-express server.

When I send request with big JSON and limiting the node to 40MB with `loadtest` libary using 20 co-current requests I see my memory keep rising and eventually getting "FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory".

At the moment I'm using this basic synchronous code with 2 seconds of starving for each job.

If I'm understanding right the operation running like single core and making each job at the time and I'm wondering - why the GC cant keep up with the load?

In addition, I read that the requests payload in the queue are stored efficiency.

I saw a lot of answers to rise the memory but lets say i cant do it, what can i do to improve the GC/Memory performance?

this is the code:

```
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "3mb" }));

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const t = new Date()
    while (t > new Date() - 2 * 1000) { }
    res.send("");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

This is how i run the node:

`node --trace_gc --inspect --max-old-space-size=40 server-test.js`

And finally, this is how i run the loadtest:

`loadtest -p loadTestJson2.JSON.txt -T application/json -c 20 http://localhost:5000`

JSON size is about 2-2.5MB

Comment: Your code has a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the code is now without syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Holy cow! With respect, your synchronous "starving" code is a bad idea. It systematically starves your Javascript instance of the resources it needs to do its work correctly.

```js
while (t > new Date() - 2 * 1000) { }     /* grossly wasteful! */
```

This operation completely ties up your tiny nodejs instance for two seconds each time it answers a request. By the time your two-second spinloop finishes and your POST function returns other requests are queued up. It seems likely the GC doesn't get a chance to run often enough; it's usually a background operation.

Plus, 40MB is a very small, too-small, working set for handling a load test of multi-megabyte-sized POST payloads.

Try allowing your code to operate concurrently by using setTimeout for your delay rather than your spinloop. That may allow your GC to run correctly.

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    setTimeout ( function () {
       res.send("")
    }, 2000)
})
```

**EDIT**: Another possibility: you could try explicitly deleting your large `req.body` objects when you're done processing each request. (They are large because your POST payloads are large.)

Put `delete req.body` right at the end of your POST handler.  I don't know if this will help, but it may. It drops a reference to the large object, and it may help GC stay ahead of your workflow.

Comment: Trying to replicate a production problem, eh? My sympathies!  If I were you I would give your production nodejs instance(s) more RAM, maybe even 4x-8x more, to work with. That's something you can do without tearing into the nodejs code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!


Yeah I totally agree that timeout and i did it because im trying replicate the problem from the production, unfortunately we do not have in the team nodejs expert and we need to fix it ASAP.

The problem is that in production we're using the node only for CPU (translation JSON to HTML) and we're getting heap out of memory errors.
I feel like our GC is not fast enough in TLDR.

I tried --optimize-for-size --gc_interval=100/0/0  but without luck.

Expanding memory is temp solution of course but we want to fix it permanently.

Comment: Don't try to run production nodejs instances on insufficient RAM. It makes no economic sense to do that. And the Javascript engine ("V8") in nodejs was not designed to run well in a memory-starved environment. A "permanent" fix probably involves configuring that server to run in a [nodejs cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) on a multicore server machine. If it uses https the fix also includes putting it behind an nginx reverse proxy, so nodejs doesn't have to handle the https crypto.

Comment: Please see my edit; I thought of something else to try.

Comment: Hey,
I tried your idea which make sense but unfortunately it didn't improved the performance